# .pfx file is needed while publishing .net MVC solution to azure

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, publishing, pfx

My .net MVC Angular based application builds successfully but when I publish it,it gives me a build error saying some `.pfx file is needed`.When I add a dummy .pfx file it works fine and publishing is successful as well. Please let me know about the role of a `.pfx file` and would it be an issue while deploying the solution in production.

Answer (score 0):

Azure offers several ways to host web sites: Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services. Which Azure Service are you leveraging? What is the exact error message you receive?

Personal Information Exchange Format (PFX) enables transfer of certificates and their private keys, this is done for securing the website.

The process of generating a certificate is comprised of two parts. First, the user creates a Certificate Signing Request, which is a textual file containing the details of the request. The user gives this file to his certificate provider of choice, and in return, gets a Certificate Response file, which he then installs on his server to complete the process and have a full certificate. To use this with your Windows Azure Web Sites, there’s a 3rd part where you export the certificate to a PFX file, which you can upload to your Azure account. Most server products have some built in mechanism to generate the CSR files and process the Certificate Response file.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm